# Can't make a 301 redirect in .htaccess file for ASP

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress site when on the same domain was an old ASPX site. This is my .htaccess file for redirection:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
redirect 301 /news/ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/category-news/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99/
redirect 301 /articles/ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/blog/articles-and-newsposts/
redirect 301 /contact.aspx http://doctrnestor.co.il/contact/
redirect 301 /send2friend.aspx http://www.doctornestor.co.il/contact/
```

So what's the problem?
When I go to "http://www.doctornestor.co.il/news" it sends me to the right URL redirection - http://www.doctornestor.co.il/category-news/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99/ but when I go to "http://www.doctornestor.co.il/contact.aspx" I'm getting this error "Server Error in '/' Application."

I'm guessing that this is because I need to do something else for redirecting ASPX. What am I missing?

P.S. I'm working on Apache.

Comment: Do you have 404 rule before your redirects that could be overruling the redirect?

Comment: yes, the default 404 redirection of wordpress...

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a typo in your question or actually a copy of your code in .htaccess?

```
redirect 301 /contact.aspx http://doctrnestor.co.il/contact/
```

I asssume this should read **doctornestor**

```
redirect 301 /contact.aspx http://doctornestor.co.il/contact/
```

Comment: The problem is that the redirect is not being preformed. This typo will only effect where the visitor is redirected to. The original problem still exists

Comment: @James True, but did I write this is your problem?

Comment: the typo is only in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# redirects
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/category-news/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99/ [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/$ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/blog/articles-and-newsposts/ [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact.aspx$ http://doctornestor.co.il/contact/ [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^send2friend.aspx$ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/contact/ [QSA,R=301,L]

# WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** first 2 redirects are exact match compared to `Redirect` directives. This means that 1 rule will ONLY match `http://www.domain.com/news/` while original Redirect would also match `http://www.domain.com/news/something` => `http://www.doctornestor.co.il/category-news/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99/something`.

If you want this behaviour replace those 2 lines with these:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/category-news/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://www.doctornestor.co.il/blog/articles-and-newsposts/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: it does not work. the problem is with the aspx URL's. not with the first two.

Comment: @Asaf Did you put all these rules in this order .. or you just copied some rules to your existing .htaccess? Please show full content your current .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

o.k. the issue was related to my host (rackspace) - [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/How_can_I_redirect_from_ASP.NET_to_PHP#Prerequisites).

@Adrian, @LazyOne & @James - thanks for your help.